# How to set working directory in Intellij for jetty launcher?

Tags: intellij-idea

By default Intellij jetty launcher sets working directory as jetty installation dir.
I need it to be project base directory because I use relative paths in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a maven goal `jetty:run` then your working directory will be the directory for that maven module.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to start jetty by IDEA launcher.